# Debian does not load X

Tags: linux, debian

I have a (little?) problem on my Debian.

When it boots, the X does not load automaticlly.
I need to log on the terminal (in any tty) and after run the command startx.

After run this command, everything works.

So, I think that I just need to configure anything to make the Debian run this command.

Comment: Your question belongs on SuperUser or the Unix Stackexchange - not StackOverflow as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Oh, thank you, Martin. I didn't know the "Unix Stackexchange".

I'll visit it.

Answer (score 2):

Debian has a script for that. To make X start on boot, execute (as root or with sudo):

```
update-rc.d xdm defaults
```

For more info, read it's manpage:

```
man update-rc.d
```

If you are using Gnome, you'll probably want to use gdm instead of xdm.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your x-server is active in your current init level.

Have a look at your */etc/inittab* for your default runlevel.

Further you should have something like

```
x:5:respawn:/usr/sbin/gdm -nodaemon
```

Comment: But how can I see which is my default run level?

Comment: Open /etc/inittab and have a look for line like "id:2:initdefault:" the keyword "initdefault" mark your default runlevel.

Comment: there is only that. No strings after the last two points.

Comment: You think that I need to change to "id:2:initdefault:x:5:respawn:/usr/sbin/gdm"  ?